# Segmentation fault on using boost syslog and cpp-netlib

Tags: boost, segmentation-fault, syslog, boost-log, cpp-netlib

After adding boost syslog into source code, segmentation fault appears inside cpp-netlib library.
I was able to prepare minimum working code snippet to reproduce the problem.

```
#include <boost/network/protocol/http/client.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/syslog_backend.hpp>

#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::network;
using namespace boost::network::http;

namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;

int main()
{
    client::request request_("http://www.boost.org/");
    client client_;
    client::response response_ = client_.get(request_);
    std::string body_ = body(response_);
    std::cout << "body: " << body_;
    using syslog_sinkT = sinks::synchronous_sink <sinks::syslog_backend>;
    boost::shared_ptr <sinks::syslog_backend> backend = boost::make_shared <sinks::syslog_backend> ();
    boost::shared_ptr<syslog_sinkT> sink = boost::make_shared <syslog_sinkT> (backend);
}
```

When last 2 lines are commented, segmentation fault disappears and everything works fine.

gdb stack trace (approximately, may vary):

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0xf7c29b40 (LWP 19874)]
0x00000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) where
#0  0x00000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x083c376c in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation::complete (bytes_transferred=260, ec=..., owner=..., 
    this=0xf6900710)
    at /home/kostidov/prj/third_party-master/boost/boost_1_60_0/__public__/v0/Linux-libc6/include/boost/asio/detail/task_io_service_o$
eration.hpp:38
#2  boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::do_run_one (ec=..., this_thread=..., lock=..., this=<optimized out>)
    at /home/kostidov/prj/third_party-master/boost/boost_1_60_0/__public__/v0/Linux-libc6/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/task_io_serv$
ce.ipp:372
#3  boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::run (ec=..., this=0x84ea280)
    at /home/kostidov/prj/third_party-master/boost/boost_1_60_0/__public__/v0/Linux-libc6/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/task_io_serv$
ce.ipp:149
#4  boost::asio::io_service::run (this=0x84e9a94)
    at /home/kostidov/prj/third_party-master/boost/boost_1_60_0/__public__/v0/Linux-libc6/include/boost/asio/impl/io_service.ipp:59
#5  0x083b5766 in boost::_mfi::mf0<unsigned int, boost::asio::io_service>::operator() (p=<optimized out>, this=<optimized out>)
    at /home/kostidov/prj/third_party-master/boost/boost_1_60_0/__public__/v0/Linux-libc6/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:49
#6  boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<boost::asio::io_service*> >::operator()<unsigned int, boost::_mfi::mf0<unsigned int, boost::a$
io::io_service>, boost::_bi::list0> (a=<synthetic pointer>, f=..., this=0x84ea94c)
    at /home/kostidov/prj/third_party-master/boost/boost_1_60_0/__public__/v0/Linux-libc6/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:249
#7  boost::_bi::bind_t<unsigned int, boost::_mfi::mf0<unsigned int, boost::asio::io_service>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<boo$
t::asio::io_service*> > >::operator() (this=0x84ea944)
    at /home/kostidov/prj/third_party-master/boost/boost_1_60_0/__public__/v0/Linux-libc6/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:1222
#8  boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<unsigned int, boost::_mfi::mf0<unsigned int, boost::asio::io_service>, boost::_bi::$
ist1<boost::_bi::value<boost::asio::io_service*> > > >::run (this=0x84ea828)
    at /home/kostidov/prj/third_party-master/boost/boost_1_60_0/__public__/v0/Linux-libc6/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:116
#9  0x0840a4f8 in boost::(anonymous namespace)::thread_proxy (param=0x84ea828) at libs/thread/src/pthread/thread.cpp:167
#10 0xf7de1f70 in start_thread () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#11 0xf7d18bee in clone () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

Problem exists on Ubuntu 14.04 with cpp-netlib 0.11.2 and both boost versions 1_58_0 and 1_60_0. Boost, cpp-netlib and my application are compiled with -std=c++11.

Note 1. Segmentation fault appears inside cpp-netlib before reaching syslog_backend creation. Only presence of last 2 lines guarantees SIGSEGV reproduction.

Note 2. Reproduces only with syslog_backend. Any other logging targets (file, consol) work fine.
The best idea I have is the problem may lay inside boost during static variables initialisation, but I have no proves regarding this version.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Is not reproducible on Mac OS X with boost 1_57_0 and Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81), tough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like I used too many compile options for building both boost and cpp-netlib.
I prepared new build for both boost and cpp-netlib once again, but this time I used as less additional options as possible. 
And it works fine.

EDIT: I found the key which causes the error. It's BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING It was defined during the boost compilation, but wasn't defined during compilation of cpp-netlib and my application.

https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11945

Comment: In my case I forgot to set definition for one of my local static libraries I use to build binary